# How to format epoch() to "20060102" or "yyyyMMdd" in Bosun

Tags: bosun

Now I want to format the result of epoch() to "yyyyMMdd" in bosun's alert section, I found out tod() cannot achieve it. Can anybody else could help me to solve it, thanks~

Comment: ElasticSearch is my backend data source and using stat_yyyyMMdd as storage index